# I can't track my own tweets using the twitter4j library

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing an application able to track some keywords from Twitter. So far I have created a FilterQuery and passed it to my TwitterStream in this way:

```
FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
filterQuery.track(new String[]{"foo1", "foo2"});
twitterStream.addListener(this)//This code is inside a class that implements StatusListener
twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the onStatus method of the class I can see that I get many posts talking about foo1 and foo2 from different people. The problem is that if I tweet a post from my own account containing the word "foo1" or "foo2" I dont get anything. Why?

Comment: it may be due to the fact that some posts arrive much later than they are posted

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the follow parameter if the key thing is to get Tweets from your specific account?

Comment: Because I don't want to get tweets only from my account, but also from my account. Otherwise off course I've have chosen the follow method.

Answer (score 1):

Because my tweets were protected. In order to make them public I went to `Settings and Privacy -> Privacy` and Safety and unchecked the `Protect your Tweets` options.